# IBM Worklight v6.1 HTTP Adapter; POST request will time out if I include a body

Tags: post, timeout, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, http-post

I've created a REST adapter to try to send and receive data from my API from. I can make POST requests and get data via defining parameters, but if I try to include a body portion to the post request, even if it is a blank valid string, the POST request times out.

Here is the time out message I get: 
(I've already attempted changing the time out time to 3600 seconds and left it going and it still timed out after the hour.)

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Invocation of procedure 'getCompanies' has timed out after 30 sec."
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

The java stack trace is below. I can make a GET/POST request to the same endpoint with no problems. It actually makes the request to my API and I get a response back. Issuing a POST with a body doesn't event hit my endpoint. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a working POST with no body:

```
function getCompanies() {

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : 'API/companies', 
        parameters: {
            api_env    : "dev",
            api_recordtype": "company",
            api_action": "GET",
            api_accept": "json",
            api_fields": "companyname,meta_universalid",            
        },
        headers: { 
           contentType   : 'application/json',
           accept        : 'application/json',
           Authorization : 'Basic amFsbGVuOm5lbGxhMTIz'
        },
    };
    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input); 
}
```

Here is a POST that causes a time out issue: (it times out no matter what I put as the body content, so I tried reducing it down to a blank string and it still times out.)

```
function getCompanies() {

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : 'API/companies', 
        parameters: {
            api_env    : "dev",
            api_recordtype": "company",
            api_action": "GET",
            api_accept": "json",
            api_fields": "companyname,meta_universalid",            
        },
        headers: { 
           contentType   : 'application/json',
           accept        : 'application/json',
           Authorization : 'Basic amFsbGVuOm5lbGxhMTIz'
        },
        body: {
           contentType   : 'application/json',
           content       : '{}'
        },
    };
    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input); 
}
```

Here is the adapter i'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
    US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<wl:adapter name="RESTAdapter"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

    <displayName>RESTAdapter</displayName>
    <description>RESTAdapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>api.demo.com</domain>
            <port>80</port> 
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
            <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
            -->     
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="getCompany"/>


    <procedure name="getCompanies" />
</wl:adapter>
```

Java stacktrace.

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project JacobsJQMApp]RESTAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project JacobsJQMApp]
Http request failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project JacobsJQMApp]java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed outjava.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:241)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.doExecute(HttpClientContext.java:178)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.execute(HttpClientContext.java:162)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.execRequest(HTTP.java:144)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTP.invoke(HTTP.java:133)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext$DirectExecutorService.execute(InvocationContext.java:284)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.submit(InvocationContext.java:138)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContextManager.submitInvocation(InvocationContextManager.java:58)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:497)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:56)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$4.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:392)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:389)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:456)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedureWithEnclosingProcedureProperties(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:440)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeDynamicProcedureWithEnclosingProcedureProperties(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1._c_anonymous_10(/integration.js:95)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_1.call(/integration.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5CUsers_5Cjallen_5CVirtual_Machines_5Cworkspace_5CJacobsJQMApp_5Cadapters_5CRESTAdapter_RESTAdapter_impl_js_65._c_getCompanies_2(C%3A%5CUsers%5Cjallen%5CVirtual+Machines%5Cworkspace%5CJacobsJQMApp%5Cadapters%5CRESTAdapter/RESTAdapter-impl.js:48)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5CUsers_5Cjallen_5CVirtual_Machines_5Cworkspace_5CJacobsJQMApp_5Cadapters_5CRESTAdapter_RESTAdapter_impl_js_65.call(C%3A%5CUsers%5Cjallen%5CVirtual+Machines%5Cworkspace%5CJacobsJQMApp%5Cadapters%5CRESTAdapter/RESTAdapter-impl.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.C_3A_5CUsers_5Cjallen_5CVirtual_Machines_5Cworkspace_5CJacobsJQMApp_5Cadapters_5CRESTAdapter_RESTAdapter_impl_js_65.call(C%3A%5CUsers%5Cjallen%5CVirtual+Machines%5Cworkspace%5CJacobsJQMApp%5Cadapters%5CRESTAdapter/RESTAdapter-impl.js)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:240)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:214)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:194)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal$1RunnableWrapper.run(ProjectLocal.java:267)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:298)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:239)
    ... 49 more

                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
```

Comment: Are you sure the destination URL is correct...?

Comment: Yes the URL was correct, we've moved away from trying to work with worklight because there were too many hoops to jump through and problems like this one that we couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The default "Timeout in seconds" for a procedure created in Worklight adapter is 30 seconds. That is why your are getting timeout after 30 seconds.
Please modify your timeout as below:

```
<procedure name="getCompanies"  requestTimeoutInSeconds="120" />
```

Comment: I've already attempted changing it to 99999 seconds and trying to let it run while I was away and it still would sit, appearing to do nothing until I got back and gave up on it after a couple hours.